# PHP yii GridView: how to highlight a row?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm using yii GridView and I would like to highlight a particular row in the following table, if a value were to equal a pre-defined value.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'filter' => $model,
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>$columns,
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:function(id, data) {$(".filters").hide();}', 
));
```

How can I do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'filter' => $model,
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>$columns,
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:function(id, data) {$(".filters").hide();}', 
    'rowCssClassExpression'=>'(($data->myproperty=="predefined_value")?"selected ":"") . ($row%2?"even":"odd")',
));
```